# how to save an array in an object at runtime in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to save an array in an object in runtime through a loop.

For example, I take an input in an array `inp=[2, 7, 20, 15, 19]` and I want to save it in an `obj={0:2, 1:7, 2:20, 3:15, 4:19}`. But, at runtime such that I have a

```js
    for(i=0;i<inp.length;i++) 
    { save each element of array into the respective object element }
```

The problem is that I have to save arrays of different lengths, these array come from taking an input from user.

I am also sorting the object afterwards and returning the indices in another array in my code. I am stuck only at how to save an array in an object during runtime. I searched a lot for a clue to get started but, I could not find anything.

Comment: An Array already is an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Autoassign: (*credit: [am not i am](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/am-not-i-am)*)

  ```
  var obj = inp.slice();
  ```
- Manual Assignment:

  ```
  var obj = {};
  for(var i=0, n=inp.length; i<n; i++) 
     obj[i]=inp[i];
  ```

---

Though an Array is technically a subclass of an Object in JavaScript, the only thing that is really happening in going from an Array to an Object, is that you're losing the native methods (`indexOf`,`concat`,`reverse`,etc) that are created during the array's construction.

Comment: If you're going to copy it, you might as well do it the fast way `var obj = inp.slice();`

Comment: No problem, welcome to SO.  If you found Derek or my answer helpful, give it an up vote and check off one of the answers that you found best answered your question.  Upvotes/Checks are at no cost to your rating, in many cases, it helps increase your rating.

Answer (score 1):

> Array is already an object

If you do some experiments, you would find out:

```
typeof([]) //<--retruns "object"
```